# Check if a file pointer is open and then delete it in C++

Tags: c++, file-pointer

Although I have read a few previously answered questions regarding a similar issue, I am not yet clear on how to go ahead.
This is the scenario:

I need to delete a few temporary files, but then they are not getting deleted. While debugging i realized that even manually trying to delete the files doesn't delete them. Hence I concluded that some file pointer has not been closed yet preventing me from deleting the file.

But then these file pointers are being used in parts of the code that are not accessible to me. This leaves me with only one solution (maybe), to check if a file pointer is open and delete it.

or is there any other way to handle the situation??

Comment: On POSIX systems, if you [`unlink`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/unlink) a file, and it's open in the same process, it will be removed when the file is closed.

Comment: Well, you've already described the solution. Attempt to delete, if it fails check the error code to see if it failed due to the file being open.

Comment: Thank you for the possible solutions. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Windows OS you can use [MoveFileEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365240%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.
This allows you do mark a file for deletion after reboot.

```
MoveFileEx(lpExistingFileName, NULL, MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT);
```

Comment: Overkill. Just call `DeleteFile`. If there are other handles open, the deletion will be postponed just as long as those handles are open.